# C code to remove in file the ^M / Windows last char?

Tags: c, linux, file, format

I would like to ask if you would know a code that would remove tailing ^M / Windows last char?

```
 2147 int convert_dos_to_unix( char *fileread ) {
 2148   int i ;
 2149   FILE *fp ;
 2150   char line[PATH_MAX];
 2151     fp = fopen( fileread ,  "r");
 2152     while( ( !feof(fp) )   ) {
 2153        if ( !feof(fp)) {
 2154           fgets(line, PATH_MAX, fp); printf ( "%s" , line);
 2155           i++;
 2156         }
 2157       }
 2158     fclose( fp );
 2159     return i ;
 2160 }
 2161
```

Thank you
Mini

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the two character sequence `\r\n` (carriage return + newline aka. line feed).

Note that your code doesn't actually read line by line, it reads chunk by chunk.  If you want to work line by line, you might look at `getline()` (see `man 3 getline`) which is a GNU extension available with glibc.  It's not standard C, but glibc is the standard linux C library.

You don't have to do that to get rid of the `\r`'s, of course.  You could stick with what you've got, but take each chunk and:

```
char *p = strchr(line, '\r');
while (p) {
    *p = '\0';
    strcat(line, ++p);
    p = strchr(p, '\r');
}
```

This finds an `\r` and replaces it with `\0`, then advances `p` one character. The `\0` truncates `line`, and then `p` is appended, removing the `\0` and shortening the whole string by one at each iteration until there are no more `\r`s to find.

Answer (score 0):

DOS files have a carriage return line feed CRLF character of `\r\n` it is represented by `^M`. All you have to do is remove this character from *near* end of the line, and you're done!

Edit: Added the `\n` character. Thanks goldilocks.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this is wrong.  CRLF is two characters, `\r\n`, so the `\r` isn't at the end of a text line.

Comment: @goldilocks Yep, you're right. Edited my answer. Still, removing the `\r` character would solve the problem.